# Spike in Tomcat Response times

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, tomcat9, response-time

I have been facing the intermittent spikes in the Rest API responses hosted on Tomcat. General response time is within 2 ms. But there are some spikes in between where one request took more than 1.5 seconds, these requests are causing the timeouts at the client end as the client is configured with very low connection timeout. This spike is occurring with in every 1 hour to 1:30 hr. There is no spike in CPU and Memory. The application is fetching Data from Redis and there are no spikes in the Redis machines as well. The number of requests processed per second is 500. The thread pool is always under utilized. Following is the Tomcat configuration.

```
<Connector port="8080"
               connectionTimeout="60000"
               maxThreads="500"
               minSpareThreads="50"
               acceptCount="2000"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               useSendfile="false"
               compression="force"
               enableLookups="false"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

The RAM of the machine is 8GB and the JVM is configured with XMS and XMX as 4GB. I am not using any explicit GC arguments. (Tomcat 9.0.26, Java 11, 4 core,8 GB RAM)

I suspect GC might be causing the issue, but as I don't see any spike in either CPU or memory I don't have any clue why this is happening. Can anyone help me by throwing some ideas in resolving this issue?

Comment: Enable GC logs. Use profilers. Measure and record latencies of DB queries and other operations throughout the request processing.

Comment: The Profiler doesn't show any spike in CPU, Memory. GC log looks fine too. The connection is closing from client within 2 seconds and the server shows all the responses were served within 20ms. The max response time was 200ms. I am not sure why the client is closing the connection.

Comment: Facing similar issue with tomcat and springboot webflux app. With 200 users testing, latency suddenly spikes from 700 ms to even 9 seconds. CPU, memory usage remains within 10% ( 8 core cpu and 16 gb ram), application is IO bound, no big computation involved in server

Comment: @mnpr Can you please let us know how this issue was resolved?